# Positive integers and negative integer

Tags: list

I've been trying to create a predicate in Prolog which splits a list of integers into a list of positive integers and into a list of negative integers. And list of positive integers contain integers which are divisible by 2 and negative integers contain integers divisible by 3

Sample query with expected result:

```
?- split([-9,6,3,4,-8,-12],X,Y).
X = [6,4],
Y = [-9,-12].
```

This is the code I got so far:

```
split([], [], []).
split([Head|Tail], [Head|List1], List2) :- Head>=0,Head mod 2==0, split(Tail, List1, List2).
split([Head|Tail], List1, [Head|List2]) :- Head<0,Head mod 3==0, split(Tail, List1, List2).
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to note that SWI-Prolog library([apply](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply)), specially when coupled with library([yall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)), offers a ready made solution to common list processing tasks:

```erlang
split(L,A,B) :-
  partition([E,C]>>(
    E>0, 0=:=E mod 2 -> C = <
  ; E<0, 0=:=E mod 3 -> C = >
  ; C = =),L,A,_,B).

?- split([-9,6,3,4,-8,-12],X,Y).
X = [6, 4],
Y = [-9, -12].
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling the case when `Head mod 2` or `Head mod 3` is not zero. You should skip the Head in that case.

```
split([], [], []).
split([Head|Tail], List1, List2) :-
    Head>=0,
    ( 0 is Head mod 2 ->
      split(Tail, ListT, List2), List1 = [Head | ListT]
    ; split(Tail, List1, List2)
    ).

split([Head|Tail], List1, List2) :-
    Head<0,
    ( 0 is Head mod 3 ->
      split(Tail, List1, ListT), List2 = [Head | ListT]
    ; split(Tail, List1, List2)
    ).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i really appreciate your help @rajashekar